# how to disable systemd service so that it does not start upon boot

Tags: debian, systemd, gpg-agent

According to https://wiki.debian.org/systemd `systemctl disable servicename` should prevent the service from starting upon boot.

If I do

```
systemctl --user stop gpg-agent
systemctl --user disable gpg-agent
```

then reboot, `gpg-agent` is still up. How do I disable that service in such sense that it does not start upon boot?

Comment: You've not told people about the error message that `systemctl` displayed to you.

Comment: `gpg-agent.service` is likely required by another service that starts during the boot up process.

Comment: @JdeBP sorry, I get `Warning: Stopping gpg-agent.service, but it can still be activated by:
  gpg-agent-browser.socket
  gpg-agent-ssh.socket
  gpg-agent.socket
  gpg-agent-extra.socket`
But I have no idea what those socket files are or how to disable them.

Comment: @leosenko this proves that `gpg-agent` is being started by those other sockets. Do you require those sockets to use the browser or ssh?

Comment: @kemotep Some time ago, put in `.bash_profile` `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent`  to start `gpg-agent` automatically. But i also need to start `ssh-agent` so i created a `systemd` unit but there were some issues and while debugging I found that the system variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` was set by `gpg-agent` so I disabled it in `.bash_profile` only to find that it is still being started up, so i wanted to disable it until i figure out what is wrong with the `systemd` unit for `ssh-agent`...

Comment: I do not understand. Do you mean that on login you need to start `gpg-agent` or that you want to figure out how to stop this from happening?

Comment: @kemotep sorry, i pressed enter accidentally.

Comment: So your ssh keys can be setup using gpg. SSH-agent should just be used to manage multiple ssh sessions and keys. Can you update your post to clarify what your setup is, what your goals are, and what you have done so far to reach those goals and any errors you have encountered? I do not think getting rid of gpg is necessary unless you really are not using gpg for ssh.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you got is helpful in understanding the problem.

```
Warning: Stopping gpg-agent.service, but it can still be activated by:   
   gpg-agent-browser.socket
   gpg-agent-ssh.socket
   gpg-agent.socket
   gpg-agent-extra.socket
```

These are units that can be disabled like the gpg-agent.service.  `systemctl --user stop gpg-agent-ssh.socket` `systemctl --user disable gpg-agent-ssh.socket` If you want to fully disable the systemd handling of gpg-agent, disable all the socket activation.

I'd suggest not doing this except diagnostically.

Comment: Acrtually instead of `--user`, `--global`might be what he needs

Comment: @TomYan I didn't test after restarting, but `--user` seemed to work on Debian 10.  After disabling all the units listed with `--user`, I was able to use my previous gpg-agent setup.  I'm not very well versed in systemd, so you may still be right.